# SpriteKit: var from GameScene.swift TO GameViewController.swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I've created a complete game in SpriteKit's GameScene.swift - In here I have the scoring system which is a simple **var** called **var currentScore = 1**.

I want to incorporate Game Center within my game too. I'm doing this by adding a button on my **Main.storyboard** but the score that I want to send to Game Center is within the GameScene.swift (the **var currentScore = 1**)

Here's the function for the scoring inside *GameScene.swift*:

```
func nextLevel(){
    currentLevel += 1
    currentScore = currentLevel
    levelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
    showLevel.text = "\(currentScore)"
    won()
    if currentLevel > highLevel{
        highLevel = currentLevel
        let Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        Defaults.setInteger(highLevel, forKey: "highLevel")
    }
```

How do I add this **currentScore** and/or **currentLevel** variable inside my GameViewController.swift? Thank you.

Comment: you can create a `SKButton` instance instead of `UIButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `currentScore` and `currentLevel` as global variables. 
For example,

```
var currentScore = 0
var currentLevel = 0
class GameScene ... {
}
```

You can access these variables in your GameViewController class because they are "Global Variables".

Comment: Thank you. For anyone that doesn't get this, you add your var above class GameScene instead of under.